# How to exclude execution of some part of the javascript code in debugging mode

Tags: javascript, debugging

This will print `testhello`:

```
var c = "test";
var d = "hello";
var e = c + d;

console.log(e);
```

But what if I just want to print `test`?

So, in debugging mode, can I exclude the execution of the statement `var d = "hello";`, and when the statement `var e = c + d;` executes, `e` will have the value `"test"` and after execution of `console.log(e)`, it will print `test`?

Comment: How should the debugger know that you want it to behave like `var d = "";` in this line?

Comment: so set a break point on `var e` line and set `d='';`

Comment: There is no way that you can achieve this programmatically. You have to do the setting manually.

Comment: But @epascarello, how could we change the value of d at runtime.

Comment: by setting it in the console....

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt Okay, thanks.

Comment: @epascarello, that worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Set up a flag you can quickly change and adjust the rest of the script accordingly

There's no way to tell javascript to behave differently based on where it's run (unless we're talking node), so the easiest way is to manually set up a boolean flag somewhere at the beginning of your script and just use its value to adjust the rest of the variables.

```
var debug = false,
    c,
    d,
    e;

c = 'test';
d = debug ? '' : 'hello';
e = c+d;

console.log(e);
```

This will print `"testhello"` if `debug` is `false`, or `"test"` if it is `true`

Comment: Okay, it means I have to write code for this, I cannot achieve this at the time of debugging the code, like we do in other programming language, we just shift the debugger from line 1 to line 10 excluding the execution of the 8 lines of code between them..

Comment: @AmansinghParihar read this question chrome don't expect to add this feature in the short run https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=6&q=skip%20line%20while%20debugging&id=382904&thanks=382904&ts=1402405661#hc6

Answer (score 0):

You can put a break point in chrome developer tools at line var e = c + d; and in console set the value of d as "". You can just write d = "" and hit enter. While executing your script now the value of d will be considered as "".

Comment: Thanks,that was suggested by @epascarello and it worked.